# How to pass a local drawable image to model class?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

When I create the object of my model class. I got this error. I don't know how to pass my local image from drawable to my model class.

This is my model class.

```
public class Drawer {

private String image;
private String title;

public Drawer(String image, String title) {
    this.image = image;
    this.title = title;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
}
```

This is my Adapter class code. I am passing the model class to the Adapter.

```
public class DrawerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DrawerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Drawer> drawerList;
ItemNavigationDrawerBinding binding;

public DrawerAdapter(List<Drawer> drawerList) {
    this.drawerList = drawerList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.item_navigation_drawer, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(binding);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(drawerList.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.binding.imgMain);
    holder.binding.tvMain.setText(drawerList.get(position).getTitle());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return drawerList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ItemNavigationDrawerBinding binding;

    private ViewHolder(@NonNull ItemNavigationDrawerBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.binding = binding;
    }
}
```

}

This is how I am creating a model class object.

```
ArrayList<Drawer> drawerList = new ArrayList<>();
drawerList.add(new Drawer(, "My Mall"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all,to save the Drawable to a class,we must use an integer value to store the Drawable id then on the adapter, set the drawable to the imageview not the drawable id.

```
 class Drawer {

    private int image;
    private String title;

    public Drawer(int image, String title) {
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

on the adapter replace
     Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(drawerList.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.binding.imgMain);

with

```
 Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(holder.itemView.getContext().getDrawable(drawerList.get(position).getImage())).into(holder.binding.imgMain);
```

finally add items like this

```
ArrayList<Drawer> drawerList = new ArrayList<>();
 drawerList.add(new Drawer(R.drawable.your_drawable,"your title"));
```